# Angular Bootstrap How can i navigate Particular Tab using ng-click

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Here im using Angular And Bootstrap nav Tab Like Below

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" ng-click="getProjectEnquiries()" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When i click on Particular Tab its Opening But i  need its should be open Programatically Soo how can i perform

```
 $scope.getProjectEnquiries = function () {
//How can I open that Tab
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `angular.element` to add the class and trigger the tab-pane

```
 $scope.getProjectEnquiries = function (element, $event) {
      //remove current active classes
      angular.element(document.querySelector(".active.show")).removeClass("active").removeClass("show");
      //adding active class so current tab will be active 
      var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector(element));
      myEl.addClass('active show');     
      //adding class to li too
      var anchorElement = angular.element($event.target.parentNode);
      anchorElement.addClass('active')

    }
```

You can check the code and demo here

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-xdukqw)

Comment: its working Goog But     <li class="active" ng-click="getRABEnquiries()"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">TAB</a></li>
                <li   ng-click="getProjectEnquiries()"><a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Project</a></li>   Its Activate TAB NOT PROJECT

Comment: Your functions are quite different, please understand my answer and then implement in yours